# Por que esta variável recebida após push nunca poderá ser nula?

Tags: flutter, dart

Recebi esse erro sobre minha variável `pickedLocation`:

> The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'true'.

Porque o compilador está dizendo que ela nunca poderá ser nula?

Além disso, porque não consigo acessar os campos `pickedLocation.latitude` e `pickedLocation.longitude`? O erro diz que não são definidos para o tipo `Future<LatLng?>`:

> The getter 'longitude' isn't defined for the type 'Future<LatLng?>'.

Esse tipo não foi definido na variável dentro da classe `MapScreen` em `LatLng? _pickedPosition` e também no *push* da navegação `push<Latlng>()`?

Essas propriedades não deveriam vir no `pop()` da classe `MapScreen`?

Segue o código:

```dart
import 'package:favourite_places_app/models/place.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MapScreen({
    super.key,
    this.initialLocation = const PlaceLocation(
      latitude: 37.422,
      longitude: -122.084,
      address: 'Googleplex',
    ),
    this.isSelecting = true,
  });

  final PlaceLocation initialLocation;
  bool isSelecting = true;

  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  LatLng? _pickedPosition;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.isSelecting ? 'Select a Location' : 'Your Place'),
        actions: [
          if (widget.isSelecting)
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(_pickedPosition);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        onTap: (position) {
          setState(() {
            _pickedPosition = position;
          });
        },
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _pickedPosition ??
              LatLng(
                widget.initialLocation.latitude,
                widget.initialLocation.longitude,
              ),
          zoom: 16,
        ),
        markers: (_pickedPosition == null && widget.isSelecting)
            ? {}
            : {
                Marker(
                  markerId: const MarkerId('m1'),
                  position: LatLng(
                    widget.initialLocation.latitude,
                    widget.initialLocation.longitude,
                  ),
                ),
              },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
  void _selectOnMap() async {
    final pickedLocation = Navigator.of(context).push<LatLng>(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MapScreen(),
      ),
    );

    if (pickedLocation == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('No Location Chosen'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }

    _savePlace(pickedLocation.latitude, pickedLocation.longitude);
  }
```

Comment: Fala Caio, bem vindo ao site. Editei um pouco sua pergunta para encaixar-se um pouco mais nos critérios do site. Pode partir desse exemplo para perguntas futuras. Além disso, a resposta que foi fornecida resolveu seu problema? Se sim, acha que pode aceitá-la? Você pode fazer isso clicando no símbolo de ✔️ ao lado da resposta. Fazer isso contribui com a categorização e eventuais buscas no site. Um abraço.

Answer (score 0):

O método [push](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) é um método que retorna um `Future<T?>`.
Isso significa que ele é assíncrono. Faz sentido, pois não sabemos por quanto tempo a tela a ser *pushada* vai ser exibida. Não temos o retorno dela imediatamente.

Então, quando você faz a linha `final pickedLocation = Navigator[...]`, sua variável `pickedLocation` é do tipo `Future<LatLng?>`, e não do `LatLng?` em si. E este Futuro nunca pode ser nulo.

Para resolver este problema, deve-se aguardar (do inglês, *await*), a informação a ser obtida. Você inclusive já marcou essa função como *async* (e curiosamente não usou `await` em nenhum lugar). Fazemos isso com a palavra `await` na frente da função que retorna o `Future`:

```dart
final pickedLocation = await Navigator.of(context).push<LatLng>(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MapScreen(),
      ),
    );
```

Aguardando a conclusão deste `Future`, podemos garantir que a variável `pickedLocation` vai ser do tipo esperado, `LatLng?`.

Entendo que é questão de estilo, mas nesse caso, se tivesse sido demarcado o tipo da variável, o compilador seria capaz de te informar o erro (talvez de forma mais clara). (Algo do tipo: `final LatLng? pickedLocation = [...]`)

Para mais informações sobre `Future`'s, `async` e `await`'s, pode-se fazer [este](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) laboratório da Google (em inglês), ou pesquisar aqui no site mesmo. Acredito que já existam perguntas sobre o tema.